# What does suffix (module) after require('file_path') mean in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I found `var log = require(libs + 'log')(module)` in a NodeAPI project but don't understand what does the suffix `(module)` mean, and what's the difference comparing to `var log = require('./log')`

Here's the line of [code](https://github.com/ealeksandrov/NodeAPI/blob/master/libs/routes/articles.js#L6)

Comment: You could _guess_ that it’s a function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require a module which in fact a function, you can call It immediately.

```
var example = function(x) {
  return x + 1;
};
module.exports = example;
```

When require:

```
require('./example')(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The module you are requiring exposes a function that takes an argument, `module`, which is the current module that you are working in. It's hard to say the exact nature without seeing the `libs/log` module itself. But it just means that the logging module requires you pass in the module you are working in. For more documentation on nodejs modules, read [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Comment: Thank you, I got it, probably should have read the doc first~

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the log.js inside libs directory, you will notice `module.exports = logger` at the end of the file, which means when you load/require `log.js` it will return you a logger function which is defined in the same `log.js` file.  logger  function takes a single argument which you are passing.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question~